# Increase percentage by user input in Java

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

If user input is higher than 100, it increases 5% percent for each unit i.e. 100 or minus return 5%, 101 return 10%, 102 return 15%, so on.

So far I was able to do this:

```
public class CalculatePercent {
    private  int numberGiven;
    private int finalPerc;

    public String numberGiven(int numberGiven) {
        this.numberGiven = numberGiven;

        if(numberGiven == 100) {
            finalPerc=5;
            return "The percentage" + " " + "is:" + " " + finalPerc + "%";
        }
        else if (finalPerc > 100 ) {

        }
        return finalPerc;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatorApp {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            CalculatePercent p = new CalculatePercent(); 

        System.out.println("Type the number: ");
        String usernumber = p.numberGiven(in.nextInt());
        System.out.println(usernumber);
    }

}
```

Comment: `String numberGiven()` method have String return type but you return `finalPerc` int variable. Either made String return type to int or Use type casting like `return String.valueOf(finalPerc)`;

Comment: Yes, i will do a cast thanks.

Comment: if number < 100 then 5 % or if number <=100 then 5% what ??????

Comment: if(numberGiven <= 100) {finalPerc=5; return "The percentage" + " " + "is:" + " " + finalPerc + "%"; }

Comment: i modified as your requirement  in answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CalculatePercent {

    private int numberGiven;
    private int finalPerc;

    public String numberGiven(int numberGiven) {
        this.numberGiven = numberGiven;
        if (this.numberGiven <= 100) {
            finalPerc = 5;
        } else if (this.numberGiven > 100) {
            finalPerc = 5 * (this.numberGiven - 99);
            /*
                Why 99 ?
                For examaple :
                100 - 99 = 1 * 5 = 5%;
                101 - 99 = 2 * 5 = 10%;
                102 - 99 = 3 * 5 = 15%
                soon
            */
        }
        return "The percentage" + " " + "is:" + " " + finalPerc + "%";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like 
return (numberGiven-99)*5

Comment: Why minus 99? The numberGiven can be any number.

Comment: How about `if (numberGiven >= 100) return (numberGiven-99 )*5;` That returns the results you requested in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the following method. I am not sure how you are organizing your classes, but the first problem is that your numberGiven method is not returning a string. The second problem is that there are some "magic numbers in here" i.e. 365. I think what you are looking for is something more like this

```
public String numberGiven(int numberGiven) {
    int finalPerc = 5;
    if (numberGiven > 100) {
        finalPerc += (numberGiven - 100)*5;
    }

    return "The percentage" + " " + "is:" + " " + finalPerc + "%";
}
```